# ajax jquery webhosting question

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have something weird going on here. I just finished a site for a client and I uploaded and I can reach the site no problem. I have a tab on the site where you click a collapsing tree and click on a topic and it calls up an article from a db. On my local development platform (xampp vista) this works nicely but once I uploaded it to the site it does not do ajax and draw the content I am calling. what could be wrong? Does it have anything to do with the way I pointed the "url" directive of ajax cos I just gave it "controller/function" (I am using Codeigniter). is this the problem?

Comment: Got some code we can look at?

Comment: are you sure the DB on the hosted site is set up properly, and all the configs are correct? 

also, have you tried firebug or some other debugger? If so, what error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the URLs being called. Check that you havent got hardcoded URLs (still refering to localhost) or errors in relative paths if they are not being resolved ie from errors whilst developing in Virtual Folders etc?

Comment: its the url's that were wrong. when developing locally, using ci you provide "controller/function" but when site goes live you have to put in the full link. Thanks muchacho, I had hardcoded links all over.

Answer (score 0):

Did you develop the project in a subdirectory and after deployment have your clients' project in the web root? May be a RewriteBase/BaseUrl issue.

You could try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) (firefox plugin) and check/debug every ajax request.

Comment: not a rewritebaseurl issue. the host does not even support it. Mike asked for code so I will post some now

Answer (score 0):

The Obvious checks, which you've probably already made:

1. The script that's actually making
   the database call, is it pointed to
   the correct database with the
   correct username and password?
2. Did you make sure that the paths are all correct when you make the ajax call (check and debug the target script of the call?

The less obvious checks:

1. There's a possibility that the ajax request is denied by the permissions set on your server. Try loading the path inside of another page (if you're using get, put the variables into the string, if you're using post, try posting synchronously with a test form).
2. The database could be running slow, which could be throwing off something on your client-side that isn't "Waiting" for the request before doing something with it. Put some console checks in for firebug or ie developer and see if things are throwing blank values.

As usual, without code we're just kind of throwing spaghetti at the wall, but hopefully something sticks! : )